# Why is re.findall not being specific in finding triplet items in string. Python

Tags: python, regex, string, findall

So I have four lines of code

```
seq= 'ATGGAAGTTGGATGAAAGTGGAGGTAAAGAGAAGACGTTTGA'



OR_0 = re.findall(r'ATG(?:...){9,}?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)',seq)
```

Let me explain what I am attempting to do first . . . I'm sorry if this confusing but I am going to try my best to explain it.

So I'm looking for sequences that START with *'ATG'* followed by units of 3 of any word char [e.g. 'GGG','GTT','TTA',etc] until it encounters either an *'TAA','TAG' or 'TGA'* I also want them to be at least 30 characters long. . . hence the {9,}?

This works to some degree but if you notice in *seq* that there is *ATG* GAA GTT GGA *TGA* AAG TGG AGG *TAA* AGA GAA GAC GTT *TGA*

So in this case, it should be finding 'ATGGAAGTTGGATGA' if it starts with the first 'ATG' and goes until the next *'TAA','TAG' or 'TGA'*

HOWEVER
when you run the OR_0 line of code, it spits back out the entire seq string.  I don't know how to make it only consider the first 'TAA','TAG' or 'TGA' followed by the first 'ATG'

If an 'ATG' is followed by another 'ATG' when read in units of 3 then that is alright, it should NOT start over but if it encounters a 'TAA','TAG' or 'TGA' when read in units of 3 it should stop.

My question, **why is re.findall finding the longest sequence of 'ATG'xxx-xxx-['TAA','TAG' or 'TGA'] instead of the first occurrence of 'TAA','TAG' or 'TGA' after an ATG separated by word characters in units of 3 ?**

Once again, I apologize if this is confusing but its messing with multiple data sets that I have based on this initial line of text and i'm trying to find out why

Comment: This would do for `OR_0` : `ATG[ATG]{3}(.*?)[ATG]` ? To match until the latest found would be `ATG[ATG]{3}(.*)[ATG]`, but if you search for the string multiple times, you will need a certain separator (like a comma or line break) to know where to end. With line breaks; *not using* `DOTALL` (`//s`) would suffice.

Comment: I hope you aren't working for gene-patenting businesses.

Comment: i'm not working with gene patenting business i'm just a biology student getting into bioinformatics @ealfonso

Comment: What should be the expected result for the input you showed? AFAIK the result you are getting is correct because any other match would be too short.

Comment: For your example, according to your description (and from some basic knowledge about DNA), for your sample input, it should not return any result. The only valid sequence is `ATGGAAGTTGGATGA` (cannot be longer, since it has been terminated by `TGA`), and the part inbetween only contains 3 codons (9 character long).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your regex to stop matching at the first `TAA|TAG|TGA`, but still only succeed if there are at least nine three letter chunks, the following may help:

```
>>> import re
>>> regexp = r'ATG(?:(?!TAA|TAG|TGA)...){9,}?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)'
>>> re.findall(regexp, 'ATGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATAG')
['ATGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATAG']
>>> re.findall(regexp, 'ATGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATAG')
['ATGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATAG']
>>> re.findall(regexp, 'ATGAAATAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATAG')
[]
```

This uses a negative lookahead `(?!TAA|TAG|TGA)` to ensure that a three character chunk is *not* a `TAA|TAG|TGA` before it matches the three character chunk.

Note though that a `TAA|TAG|TGA` that does *not* fall on a three character boundary will still successfully match:

```
>>> re.findall(regexp, 'ATGAAAATAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATAG')
['ATGAAAATAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATAG']
```

Comment: Actually, `?` in `{9,}?` in not necessary. The negative look-ahead has already disallow the ending sequences to be part of the repeated portion, so we can do a greedy match. Aside from that, good solution so +1

Comment: @nhahtdh You're right, the greedy `{9,}?` is now redundant. I forgot to remove it when I copied the pattern from the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the length is not a requirement then it's pretty easy:

```
>>> import re
>>> seq= 'ATGGAAGTTGGATGAAAGTGGAGGTAAAGAGAAGACGTTTGA'
>>> regex = re.compile(r'ATG(?:...)*?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)')
>>> regex.findall(seq)
['ATGGAAGTTGGATGA']
```

Anyway I believe, according to your explanation, that your previous regex is actually doing what you want: searching for matches **of at least 30 characters** that start in `ATG` and end in `TGA`.

In your question you first state that you need matches of at least 30 characters, and hence you put the `{9,}?`, but after that you expect to match *any* match. You cannot have both, choose one. If length is important than keep the regex you already have and the result you are getting *is correct*.

Comment: The regex in the question does not stop at the first occurrence of ending sequence (counting from the starting sequence ATG).

Comment: @nhahtdh By what I understand reading the question that's not what the OP wants. As I already said in a comment he should provide more example of input/expected output, since having three lines of examples would be worth a thousand lines of description by words...

Comment: That's true - his example is not consistent with his description. (Anyway, it is best to have both example and description - example to quickly show what one wants to match, and description to cover the process).

Comment: oh i see! ok yes that makes sense . . . its looking for ATG followed by at least 10 sets of 3 and then TAA,TGA, or TAG.  Those triplets in between can be a TAA,TGA, or TAG by the way the code is set up. i see the problem now

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions.

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
    from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/1561176
    """
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

def method(sequence, start=['ATG'], stop=['TAA','TAG','TGA'], min_len=30):
    response = ''
    started = False
    for x in chunks(sequence, 3):
        if x in start:
            started = True
            response += x
        elif x in stop and started:
            if len(response) >= min_len:
                yield response + x
                response = ''
                started = False
            else:
                response += x
        elif started:
            response += x
    yield response

for result in method('ATGGAAGTTGGATGAAAGTGGAGGTAAAGAGAAGACGTTTGA'):
    print result
```

If I use the min_len of 30, the return is:

```
ATGGAAGTTGGATGAAAGTGGAGGTAAAGAGAAGACGTTTGA
```

If I use a min_len of 0, the return is:

```
ATGGAAGTTGGATGA
```

Comment: The result you are getting is wrong. The OP clearly stated that "I also want them to be at least 30 characters long. . . hence the `{9,}?`", and I don't think the result you are getting is 30 characters long.

Comment: The OP says the result should be the result I am getting. "So in this case, it should be finding 'ATGGAAGTTGGATGA' if it starts with the first 'ATG' and goes until the next 'TAA','TAG' or 'TGA'" . However, if the requirement is minimum 30, there is no problem to add that to this answer. But I would want to know what happens if a valid match is found that is not the length requirement.

Comment: That's why I commented also his question. It's not clear what he wants. Also, if the length is not a requirement simply replacing the `{9,}?` with `*?` would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
seq= 'ATGGAAGTTGGATGAAAGTGGAGGTAAAGAGAAGACGTTTGA'
OR_0 = re.findall(r'ATG(?:.{3})*?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)',seq)
```

Comment: The requirement of at least 30 characters is not met.